# Access and bind data from nested 0 index Json data in Angular 5

Tags: json, angular5, ngfor

I am trying to display data from an API's json result in my html using angular 5. I am unable to do i guess due to unnecessary 0 indexes in my json, kindly help.
My json looks like -

```
{
    "Plans": [
        [{
            "PlanId": 1,
            "PlanName": "Free"
        }, {
            "PlanId": 2,
            "PlanName": "Regular"
        }, {
            "PlanId": 3,
            "PlanName": "Premium"
        }]
    ],
    "Location": [
        [{
            "States": [{
                "StateId": 1,
                "Country_Id": 1,
                "StateName": "Alabama"
            }, {
                "StateId": 2,
                "Country_Id": 1,
                "StateName": "Alaska"
            }, {
                "StateId": 3,
                "Country_Id": 1,
                "StateName": "Arizona"
            }, {
                "StateId": 34,
                "Country_Id": 1,
                "StateName": "North Dakota"
            }, {
                "StateId": 50,
                "Country_Id": 1,
                "StateName": "Wyoming"
            }],
            "CountryId": 1,
            "CountryName": "United States of America",
            "CountryCode": "USA"
        }, {
            "States": [{
                "StateId": 51,
                "Country_Id": 2,
                "StateName": "Alberta"
            }, {
                "StateId": 52,
                "Country_Id": 2,
                "StateName": "British Columbia"
            }, {
                "StateId": 53,
                "Country_Id": 2,
                "StateName": "Manitoba"
            }, {
                "StateId": 54,
                "Country_Id": 2,
                "StateName": "New Brunswick"
            }, {
                "StateId": 63,
                "Country_Id": 2,
                "StateName": "Yukon"
            }],
            "CountryId": 2,
            "CountryName": "Canada",
            "CountryCode": "CA"
        }]
    ]
}
```

[Image for 0 indexes I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE30q.png)

I am trying to dynamically generate PlanNames i.e, Free, Regular,

```
<b>
<div class="col-md-4 text-center"*ngFor="let dummy of Plans" >
   <div class="panel panel-pricing" >
       <div class="panel-heading" >
           <h3>{{dummy.PlanName}}</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="panel-body text-center">
           <p><strong>$100 / Month</strong></p>
       </div>
       <div class="panel-footer">
           <div class="radio">
               <label><input type="radio" name="planradiogroup" id="planradio{{dummy.PlanId}}" [checked]="idx === 0" [value]="dummy.id" (change)="onSelectionChange(dummy)">Option {{dummy.PlanId}}</label>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</b>
```

My Component -

`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   readonly apiTravelPlans = "http://localhost:50749/api/TravelGetDetails?type=json";
   plans: any = typeof {};

   constructor (private http:HttpClient){
      this.ngOnInit().subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);
       this.plans = data;
      });
    }
   posts: Observable<any>;

   getPosts() {
    this.posts = this.http.get(this.apiTravelPlans) //not used
   }

  ngOnInit(){
    return this.posts = this.http.get(this.apiTravelPlans) // using to load json before my html
  };
}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you indent the JSON, the structure becomes much easier to understand.

`Plans` is an array containing a single element, which is also an array.

So, if you really can't fix this structure, you need

```
*ngFor="let dummy of Plans[0]"
```

EDIT:

Now that you've posted your code, many other mistakes become apparent.

You're trying to use `Plans` from your template, but your component doesn't have any property named `Plans`. You have one named `plans` which, for an obscure reason, is initialized with `typeof {}` (why?).

You call `this.ngOnInit()` from your constructor. Again, that makes no sense. ngOnInit is a hook of your component, **called by angular automatically**. You must **not** call it. And its return type is supposed to be `void`.

The variable `plans` is initialized asynchronously. So you must test that it's defined (or that its fields are defined if you initialize it to an empty object) before trying to access it. Otherwise, you'll have an error by trying to access field of an object that will be initialized later, asynchronously.

And `plans` isn't the field `Plans` of your JSON. It's the enclosing object.

So, in short, your component should look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 obj: any; // you should define an interface instead of using any, and choose a good name torefer to the json object

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:50749/api/TravelGetDetails?type=json')
      .subscribe(json => this.obj = json);
  };
}
```

And the view should look like this:

```
<div *ngIf="obj">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center"*ngFor="let dummy of obj.Plans[0]">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input sir, I've already tried *ngFor="let dummy of Plans[0]" but it is not working.

Comment: Define "not working", precisely. Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I am not able to generate my Div elements using ngFor in this case, Nothing is generated in my HTML

Comment: Again, post a complete minimal example. What is printed when you add `{{ Plans | json }}` to your template? Do you at least have a `Plans` field in your component? How is it initialized? Post a complete minimal example.

Comment: Updated my question with controller and nothing came up in my html `::before ::after`

Comment: can help on the other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500671/angular-5-form-validation-not-accessing-validators-properties

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone:

```
console.log(this.selectedRequest['interviewDetails']['interviewDate1']);
```

so interviewDate1 is a property of interviewDetails which is a property/object on selectedRequest.